# Copy and Paste Filtered Data from one Spreadsheet to another using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy filtered data from one spreadsheet and paste it onto another using a macro but I receive an error when the code runs. What I have is as follows:

```
Sub Unmet_Projects()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set x = ThisWorkbook

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\turnbull\Documents\Global Unmet Demand\1-    extract-Unmet projects.xls")
Set ws = x.Sheets("Unmet Projects")
Set sh = y.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = sh.Range("A1:CA100").Offset(1,     0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
x.Sheets("Unmet Projects").Range("L3").PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which error are you obtaining? Btw, why do not you try to have `Set rng = sh.Range("A2:CA100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` instead of making the offset?

Comment: if you want copy filtered data you have to use sh.AutoFilter.Range.Copy

Comment: The error is Object required on the set rng = line. You are correct, I do not need to include the offset. Although the error still occurs without the offset